# Java: Triangle rotation - unsuccessful concept

Tags: java, matrix, vector, rotation

What do I do wrong? I get incorrect results (coordinates).

A triangle (see the picture below: blue is the original triangle, lime is the rotated one: a clone. Edge A is a fixed point).

[image]
The classes I use:

A Point class:

```
public class Point {
   private final double x;
   private final double y;
   public Point(double x, double y) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
   }
   public double getX() {
      return x;
   }
   public double getY() {
      return y;
   }
   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return "[(" + x + ") (" + y + ")]";
   }
}
```

An abstract Object2D class:

```
public abstract class Object2D {
    Point[] point;
    public Point getPoint(int i) {
        return point[i];
    }
    public double getLowestX() {
        return Arrays.asList(point).stream()
            .mapToDouble(Point::getX)
            .min().getAsDouble();
    }
    public double getHighestX() {
        return Arrays.asList(point).stream()
            .mapToDouble(Point::getX)
            .max().getAsDouble();
    }
    public double getLowestY() {
        return Arrays.asList(point).stream()
            .mapToDouble(Point::getY)
            .min().getAsDouble();
    }
    public double getHighestY() {
        return Arrays.asList(point).stream()
            .mapToDouble(Point::getY)
            .max().getAsDouble();
    }
    public double getLength() {
        return getSide(getLowestX(), getHighestX());
    }
    public double getHeight() {
       return getSide(getLowestY(), getHighestY());
    }
    private double getSide(double v1, double v2) {
        return (v1 < v2) ? (0 - v1) + v2 : (0 - v2) + v1;
    }
    @Override
       public String toString() {
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       for (Point pt : point) sb.append(pt).append("\n");
       return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

A Line class:

```
public class Line extends Object2D {
   public Line(Point point0, Point point1) {
      point = new Point[2];
      point[0] = point0;
      point[1] = point1;
   }
   public double getLineLength() {
      return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(getLength(), 2) + Math.pow(getHeight(), 2));
   }
}
```

My Triangle class:

```
public class Triangle extends Object2D {
    public Triangle(Point point0, Point point1, Point point2) {
        point = new Point[3];
        point[0] = point0;
        point[1] = point1;
        point[2] = point2;
    }
    public static Triangle getRotatedTriangle(Triangle triangle) {
       Point point0 = triangle.getPoint(0);
       Point point1 = triangle.getPoint(1);
       Point point2 = triangle.getPoint(2);
       Line baseLine = new Line(point0, point1);
       double rotationHeight = baseLine.getHeight();
       double baseLength = baseLine.getLineLength();
       double sinA = rotationHeight / baseLength;
       double angle = Math.asin(sinA);
       double cosA = Math.cos(angle);                  
       point1 = new Point(
            (point1.getX() * cosA - point1.getY() * sinA),
            (point1.getX() * sinA + point1.getY() * cosA));
       point2 = new Point(
            (point2.getX() * cosA - point2.getY() * sinA),
            (point2.getX() * sinA + point2.getY() * cosA));
       return new Triangle(point0, point1, point2);
   }
}
```

And, of course, my main class:

```
public class TestDrive {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          Triangle triangle = new Triangle (
             new Point(-6.5, -1.5),
             new Point(2.5, 7.5),
             new Point(6.5, -5.5)
          );
          System.out.println(triangle);
          System.out.println(Triangle.getRotatedTriangle(triangle));
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made 2 mistakes in your code:

- You are trying to rotate with the angle α when you should be rotating with the angle -α (since you are rotating clockwise).
- Your multiplication matrix is incorrect: your code will perform a rotation around the origin of the XY plane instead of rotating around the point A. For the point `(x, y)` rotated by the rotation matrix `R` around the center `(a, b)`, the correct formula for the new rotated point `(x', y')` would be `(x', y') = R * (x - a, y - b) + (a, b)`.

This should be enough for you to correct your code. As reference, here's the solution I get for the rotated triangle:

```
[(-6.5) (-1.5)]
[(6.227922061357855) (-1.5000000000000009)]
[(-0.1360389693210724) (-13.520815280171309)]
```

Comment: :) Thank you! I just found it out too. Now it's time for corrections.